How to give absolute path in scala for dataset on remote server
Detailed Background: I have to execute a scala jar file (containing probability algo implementation) on a remote cluster which has the big data set in one of the subfolders. So I create jar file locally, then scp to remote server, and connect to remote server using ssh and then execute the jar file in the ssh shell calling 'spark-submit --master'. In my program file, I have coded for the relative path "spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt".
The working folder once I connect to ssh shell is: //home/doe
The jar file is scp to this working folder: //home/doe (when I do 'dir', I can see the jar file in this location)
The dataset is in subfolder "/spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"
Command line in ssh shell starts with: doe@isabelle:~$ (Similar to executing cmd on local machine and for me it defaults to: "C:\users\doe>")
However, the jar file gives the error (in stderr): "Input path does not exist: file:/home/doe/spark/work/driver-20241221145010-0001/spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"
Looks like the jar file is getting executed in one of the worker nodes and program appends the relative path of dataset file, which obviously becomes incorrect.
QUESTION: How do I instead give absolute path of the dataset file in the program?
Also, access to this remote server is restricted to students and I get my next attempt after 2 weeks. Is there any other remote server available for developers to connect and test?
Program Constraints to be complied with: JDK 8, Scala: 2.13.15, Spark: 3.3.0
Current program code:
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

// File path
val filePath = "spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"

// Load data
val gData: RDD[String] = sc.textFile(filePath)

// Check if file exists
println("Checking for Dataset File Exists..")
if (File(filePath).exists) {
  println(s"File $filePath exists.")
} else {
  println(s"File $filePath does not exist.")
}

I tried a few combination for filepath but nothing seems to work:
filePath = "//home/doe/spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"

filePath = ":/home/doe/spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"

filePath = "~/spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"

filePath = "spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"

filePath = "/spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"


A single slash should be enough for absolute path: "/home/doe/spark/data/mllib/bigdata.txt"

Is there any other remote server available for developers to connect and test? Don't think so but you can test in local on your machine. Spark can run in local for tests.
